# How to get Linux accept packets destined to non-local addresses?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ipv6

I have a scenario where our Linux running box has to receive packets destined to non-local addresses. e.g. I don't have 1::1 configured on any of my box's interfaces, but I want to have packets destined to it received. I have got the packets reaching `ip6_rcv_finish()`.

Here `ip6_input_route()` returns a dst_entry pointing to discard function. If I add 1::1 to one of the interfaces, I see `ip6_input_route()` returns dst_entry wtih `ip6_input()` and the packet is received by the app through the socket. Is there a way to achieve this without having to add the address explicitly?

I am using IP_BINDTODEVICE and IP_TRANSPARENT options. These options let me bind the socket to 1::1 even though the address is not configured on any interface.

Comment: Updating with another related question. Isn't IP_TRANSPARENT expected to help here? If you have an option to bind to non-local address, should it also not provide for receiving packets for that address? Otherwise what is use of just binding to non-local address and not receiving packets for the same?

Comment: For those of you unfamiliar with the "compressed IP format" being used here, see http://www.gestioip.net/docu/ipv6_address_examples.html

Answer (score 0):

If you configure your neighbor router/host with a route to the destination of 1::1 to go out the interface you are connected to...it will reach you.

Answer (score 0):

The `IP_TRANSPARENT` setting uses TProxy, which is documented [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt).  The tricky part seems to be getting the packets sent to the interface the socket is bound to.  Adapting the instructions in the documentation for IPv6, you should do the following:

```
# Mark packets whose destination IPs match a local socket
ip6tables -t mangle -N DIVERT
ip6tables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
ip6tables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 1
ip6tables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT

# Configure policy routing to allow marked packets
ip -6 rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip -6 route add local default dev eth1 table 100
```

Note that `eth1` in the route was the interface my socket was bound to.  You may have to play around with these settings to get it to work correctly.  See [here](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Tproxy4#Routing_configuration) for more info.

I tested this in a two-box Vagrant environment and was able to successfully perform a TCP handshake with a socket bound to a bogus IPv6 address.

Comment: Adding to lo would help. But the requirement is for several IP addresses.

Comment: @user7420724  I completely rewrote my answer.  Let me know if this helps!